# Dart multiple function calls/set variables all on one line

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to clear some Lists at the start of a function otherwise they just get larger and larger with an `add` method, so I can either use `= []` or `.clear()` to achieve this, but the formatting puts them all on separate lines like this:

```
listone.clear();
listtwo.clear();
three.clear();
listfour.clear();
listfive.clear();
listsix.clear();
```

I want to do something like this but it won't allow it:

`listone.clear(), listtwo.clear(), three.clear(), listfour.clear(), listfive.clear(), listsix.clear();`

or

`listone = [], listtwo = [], three = [], listfour = [], listfive = [], listsix = [];`

How do I set multiple variables that have already been declared all on the same single line?

Comment: Can you say *why* you want the operations to be on one line?

Comment: Does it really matter why? I try to do things in a similar manner for space efficiency whenever I can. It is much more satisfying for whatever reason.

Comment: @MostHated Yeah it was a terrible question he asked. Nobody wants a long block of code when they can put it on one line, unless it would make it unreadable but clearly that's not the case here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you can do

```
void main() {
  var listone = [1, 2], listtwo = [1, 1, 1], listthree = [0, 0, 1];

  [listone, listtwo, listthree].forEach((l) => l.clear());

  print(listone);
  print(listtwo);
  print(listthree);
}
```

Check at [dartpad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/)

**Note:** There should be no trailing comma like `[x,y,z  , /*this one*/]` or dartfmt will take it to next line.

**EDIT:**

Also, if using the same thing in multiple files then

put in a global file

```
clearList(List list)=>list.clear();
```

and call something like

```
[listone, listtwo, listthree].forEach(clearList);
```

Comment: This answer is great and seems to work perfectly. At least somebody actually took the time to read the question...unlike the other useless answer.

Comment: You feel the first approach is cumbersome? Why is that.

Comment: `(l) => l.clear()` every time for do the same thing

Comment: suppose you want to change your approach to clearing the list, maybe you want the list data before clearing it. If you go by first approach,then good luck finding and replacing all the calls. In the second approach you change the global function and you are done.

Comment: Ok I see. Anyway it's a great answer.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to make complex things fit in less space is to use a helper method.

```
clearAll(Iterable<List<Object>> lists) {
  for (var list in lists) list.clear();
}
```

then you just write:

```
clearAll([listone, listtwo, three, listfour, listfive, listsix]);
```

You can inline the helper function

```
for (var l in [listone, listtwo, three, listfour, listfive, listsix]) l.clear();
```

but it probably won't fit on one line anyway.

If you are setting variables, and you set the variables to *the same value*, then you can do multiple assignments as a single expression:

```
listone = listtwo = three = listfour = listfive = listsix = [];
```

Not really recommended for lists because then all variables will point to the *same* list object. It works better when assinging `null` or another immutable value.
It's not particularly *readable* either.

There is no simple way in Dart to execute multiple expressions in a single statement without some helper.

You could declare:

```
void do6(void v1, void v2, void v3, void v4, void v5, void v6) {}
...
do6(listone.clear(), listtwo.clear(), three.clear(), 
    listfour.clear(), listfive.clear(), listsix.clear());
```

but you will likely find that will be formatted on more than one line as well

Alternatively, just use a list literal instead of a function parameter list to allow multiple expressions:

```
[listone.clear(), listtwo.clear(), three.clear(), 
 listfour.clear(), listfive.clear(), listsix.clear()];
```

Same caveats about length and formatting, and it's confusion and inefficient that the list is created and then not used.

All in all, please don't try to be clever with formatting. Just write idiomatic code, your readers will have a much easier time understanding it, and the compiler will be more efficient that way.

Comment: Interesting ideas. I tried your last method `[listone.clear(), listtwo.clear(), three.clear(),  listfour.clear(), listfive.clear(), listsix.clear()];` and vscode underlines it and says 'avoid using unnecessary statements'. Not sure what that's about.

Comment: `listone = listtwo = three = listfour = listfive = listsix = [];` and then `listone.add(10);` modifies every list. How to prevent this?

Comment: your first method seems to be the most readable one and best approach; +1 for that

Comment: No way to avoid all the lists being the same list value if you use multiple assignment. Good point that that is probably not what the OP wants.

Comment: I see that `a = b = c = d = null` works even if `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` have different types. Is this multiple assignment a safe option?

Comment: Yes, the assignment is safe. The static type of the assignment is the type of the right-hand-side expression, so because `null` has type `Null`, `d = null` also has type `Null` no matter what type `d` has. An expression of the form `(x = e)` can be used anywhere `e` can be used, as long as `e` can safely be assigned to `x`.